# How to improve the performance of webdav

Tags: file-transfer, webdav, cheroot, wsgidav

I am using [WsgiDAV](https://github.com/mar10/wsgidav) which is a generic and extendable WebDAV server based on WSGI which is using cheroot HTTP server.
The issue that i am facing is that the upload and download speed to/from the webdav is very slow. On windows it is about .33 mbps and on mac it is .6 mbps. I have done alot of research about improving the performance but to to avail.
webdav is hosted on a windows server 2016 OS

I tried increasing the thread count, limiting logging, tried with and without ssl but nothing seems to work.

In the logs i can see that there are multiple request for each resource one from the authorized user and one from anonymous user which is almost every time 401 unauthorized.

Also when uploading to webdav upload progress bar shoot upto 90-95% showing high speed of data transfer and then stays there are a very long time and then finishes and this happens almost everytime.

Can anyone point me in a direction as to what has to be done to improve the performance. I tried with the old versions and the new version 3.0.3 but the performance almost remains the same.

```
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:18] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  84.121.236.116 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:18] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=0, elap=0.002sec -> 207 Multi-Status
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:18] "PROPFIND /desktop.ini" length=0, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:18] "PROPFIND /desktop.ini" length=0, depth=0, elap=0.001sec -> 404 Not Found
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:18] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=1, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:18] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=1, elap=0.067sec -> 207 Multi-Status
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "PROPFIND /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=0, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "PROPFIND /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=0, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 404 Not Found
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=0, elap=0.001sec -> 207 Multi-Status
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "PUT /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=0, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "PUT /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=0, elap=0.000sec -> 201 Created
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "LOCK /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=199, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:21] "LOCK /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=199, depth=infinity, elap=0.005sec -> 200 OK
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:22] "HEAD /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" elap=0.005sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:48:22] "HEAD /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" depth=0, elap=0.005sec -> 200 OK
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:48:22] "PUT /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=24674726, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PUT /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=24674726, elap=33.691sec -> 204 No Content
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPPATCH /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=443, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPPATCH /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=443, depth=0, elap=0.010sec -> 207 Multi-Status
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPPATCH /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=443, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPPATCH /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=443, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 207 Multi-Status
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "UNLOCK /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "UNLOCK /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" elap=0.001sec -> 204 No Content
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPFIND " length=0, depth=0, elap=0.001sec -> 207 Multi-Status
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPFIND /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=0, depth=0, elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "PROPFIND /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" length=0, depth=0, elap=0.005sec -> 207 Multi-Status
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - (anonymous) - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "GET /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" elap=0.000sec -> 401 Not Authorized
INFO    :  64.121.191.119 - admin - [2020-09-23 18:49:28] "GET /Fel PPv4_new2.mp4" depth=0, elap=0.005sec -> 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the latest version of cheroot?
There was a [known performance problem](https://github.com/mar10/wsgidav/issues/149) that was fixed in cheroot 8.1., I think.

Comment: Yes i tried the latest version of cheroot but the performance remains the same, be it old version or be it new version.